# my android app crash on arabic system

Tags: java, android, wordpress, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm beginner to android development , my app works fine but its crashing if the android system language changed to Arabic 
below is my log

> 01-03 08:50:20.150: D/AndroidRuntime(1351): Shutting down VM 01-03
>   08:50:20.150: W/dalvikvm(1351): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xb19feba8) 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351): Process: com.miniawy.wordpress, PID: 1351
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188) 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.miniawy.wordpress.fragment.FraMain.setAllPostsForCategory(FraMain.java:792)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.miniawy.wordpress.fragment.FraMain.defineAndFillData(FraMain.java:440)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.miniawy.wordpress.MainActivity.defineAndFillData(MainActivity.java:229)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.miniawy.wordpress.wordpress.FetchRecentPostsByCategory.onPostExecute(FetchRecentPostsByCategory.java:158)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.miniawy.wordpress.wordpress.FetchRecentPostsByCategory.onPostExecute(FetchRecentPostsByCategory.java:1)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632) 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 01-03
>   08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-03
>   08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 01-03
>   08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-03
>   08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-03 08:50:20.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   01-03 08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 01-03
>   08:50:20.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-03 08:55:20.690:
>   I/Process(1351): Sending signal. PID: 1351 SIG: 9

source `/**
     * Removes the progress bar that shows loading of the news list
     */
    public void removeNewsListLoading() {
        this.mListNewsLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

```
/**
 * Removes the progress bar that shows loading of slider
 */
public void removeSlidingLoadingView() {
    this.mSliderLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/**
 * Sets all post for a given category
 * 
 * @param allPostsForCategory
 *            list of all posts for a given category
 */
public void setAllPostsForCategory(ArrayList<Post> allPostsForCategory,
        boolean addMore) {
    if (!addMore) {
        this.mAllPostsForCategory.clear();
    }
    this.mAllPostsForCategory.addAll(allPostsForCategory);
}

/**
 * Marks the share dialog as opened
 * 
 * @param openedContextShareDialog
 *            layout of the share dialog
 */
public void setOpenedContextShareDialog(
        LinearLayout openedContextShareDialog) {
    if (openedContextShareDialog != null) {
        this.mOpenedContextShareDialog = openedContextShareDialog;
    }
}

/**
 * Shares a post via Facebook by given index
 * 
 * @param postIndex
 *            index of the post to be shared
 */
@Override
public void shareViaFacebook(int postIndex) {
    if (mOpenedContextShareDialog != null
            && mOpenedContextShareDialog.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mOpenedContextShareDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (NetworkManager.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mListPosts.get(postIndex)
                .getTitle());
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mListPosts.get(postIndex)
                .getUrl());
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                shareIntent, 0);
        boolean hasFacebookApp = false;
        for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
            if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                        activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                startActivity(shareIntent);
                hasFacebookApp = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!hasFacebookApp) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "There is no Facebook app installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connectivity),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

`

Comment: More information (source code) should be provided. It's evidently that you have NPE in this part of code: FraMain.setAllPostsForCategory(FraMain.java:792). Sounds like after language changing some of your data is not initialized correctly.

Comment: i added the source code

Comment: you know now that at this line you have NPE - this.mAllPostsForCategory.addAll(allPostsForCategory);  Did you try to debug app? I think once you do it it'll be clear for you why it happened.

Comment: i made debug but it don't show anything